# How to retrieve pictures from guest account?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos

I have saved pictures in my MacBook Air on a Guest Account. I am trying to locate my pictures in guest account but am unable to find it. How can I retrieve these?

Answer (score 1):

On an Apple guest account, the home directory is wiped each time you logout or shutdown. That's why it's called a 'guest account', because it is meant to be temporary.

You will need a tool to recover deleted files if they have not been overwritten by new files in the time between when they were deleted and now.

Comment: What recovery tools do you recommend?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I've never had to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to recover those pictures unless you're willing to try out some paid tools for recovering information from a disk (there's no guarantee even in that case).

*A guest account is temporary* - a home folder is created only for the duration while the user is logged in. The moment the guest user logs out, all files are deleted from the system.

Read **[OS X Mountain Lion: Set up guest users](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11321)** for more details on the restrictions and limits on a guest user account. Here's a snippet from that page that has been around even in past versions of OS X (emphasis mine):

> **Important: Files created by a guest user are deleted when the user logs out. A temporary home folder is created for the guest user’s files, but this folder and its contents are deleted when the user logs out.**